# proof that function is constant

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

I'm annoyed by quite a simple problem in calculus (I apologize in advance if I'm not using adequate terms in English, I don't take the course in English nor am I a native speaker):

Let $f:\mathbb R\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ be a function which is continuous at $0$ and satisfies $f(x)=f(2x)\,\forall x\in\mathbb R$.

My question is how do I formally prove that for every $x<0$ $f(x)=c_1$, and for every $x>0$ $f(x)=c_2$, where $c_1,c_2\in \mathbb R$?
After proving those two statements (or at least one of them WLOG) it would be quite easy to prove that $f(0)=c_1=c_2$ by the definition of continuity of $f(0)$ and thus $f(x)$ is constant.
Those two statements are just so obvious to see that I can't think of any formal way of proving so without "cheating".
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The identity can be written 
$$
f(x)=f\left(\frac{1}{2}x\right)
$$
and you can prove by induction that
$$
f(x)=f\left(\frac{1}{2^n}x\right)
$$
for every integer $n\ge0$. But
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}f\left(\frac{1}{2^n}x\right)=\dots
$$